# Chrome copy XPath returning null using HTMLAgilityPack (removed 'tbody')

Tags: c#, google-chrome, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to pull the data from the tables on the page http://www.pgatour.com/players/player.24502.adam-scott.html/season

But the Xpath I copy from chrome is returning a null reference. I've tried several variations but nothing is working, I've never used XPath before, am I missing something?

```
string Url = "http://www.pgatour.com/players/player.24502.adam-scott.html/season";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

var firstTournamentDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='player-season-details-table']/div/table/tr[2]/td[1]");
```

Note: I've removed the `tbody` axis step from the XPath that chrome produced.

**Edit:**

the `firstTournamentDate` variable is null then if I try this:

```
var x = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='player-season-details-table']/div/table/tr[2]/td[1]", index)[0].InnerText;
```

it throws a `null reference exception`

Comment: Where do you get null? `SelectNodes` would return a node list that can be empty but never null, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically using AJAX. You cannot simply access it with an XPath expression without executing the JavaScript, for example using Selenium.

But using Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools and monitoring the "Network" tab, you can try to find out which URL is requested. I think you're looking for

```
http://www.pgatour.com/data/players/24502/2014results.json
```

which returns the table content as easily to parse JSON objects.

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks for the help, I'll do some research into deserializing that data in to my POCO classes.

Comment: Hey, that JSON url only seems to have part of the data in that table, I can't find the GIR stats in the other json requests either. I'll try your first suggestion - using 'Selenium'

Comment: Jens, would you be able to point in the right direction with using Selenium please?

Comment: Sorry, never used it myself. Don't know what interfaces exist from C#.

Comment: Gah this is proving to be difficult, I don't really understand the problem. How would I execute the required JavaScript?

Comment: Well, selenium includes a headless browser that renders the site as a normal browser would do, thus the javascript gets executed. I still guess trying to find out where the data comes from will be the better, easier, faster and more stable solution.